# create method in store function stores array value in db

Tags: laravel

```
  $array = array($t, $c, $s);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        receipt::create($a);
    }
```

i want to pass the array content to database but i got this error
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, string given,

Comment: because your $t, $c, $s is not array

Comment: @J.Doe how is that? i used the function array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually while insert we should provide the array data even single field or more no of fields.

> For example two fields : receipt::create($a). In this $a should contain two values in array format.

New example updated below as per your request. In this your $a variable should be like below format

```
$a = array(
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'receipt_description' => $desc
);
$receiptId = receipt::create($a)->id;
```

Comment: can i have more detailed explanation please ? @Sheik

Comment: Updated answer for you. Please check